# How to clear cache from multiple Firefox profiles?

Tags: firefox, firefox-profile

I am managing a system with 200+ Firefox profiles, each of which has its own folder with cookies, cache, etc.

The cache files for each profile consume around 1GB and the system's hard drive is filling up.

Is there an easier way to clear these caches than to go into each profile and press clear?

Is it safe to just delete the "cache2" folder in each one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you may delete the contents of all `cache2` folders.

You can also [limit the size of the cache](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1219833) via these two preferences:

```
browser.cache.disk.capacity (max: 1048576; 1024 MB)
browser.cache.disk.smart_size.enabled (false)
```